# Display or do not display text box based on check box in C#

Tags: c#

Do you guys have any idea on doing a winform that will detect the checkbox to see whether it will display a text box or not? For example, if the checkbox is checked, there will be a textbox. If the checkbox is unchecked, the textbox will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your checkbox checked event handler...

```
textBox1.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
```

..if you want it the other way around, you can do this:

```
textBox1.Visible = !checkBox1.Checked;
```

Note the exclamation mark, which means "not".

Comment: But I want the textbox to be invisible when checked. How?

Comment: on load event you set textBox1.Visible = false;

Comment: OK. I've done it             if (checkBox3.Checked == true) textBox1.Visible = false;
            else textBox1.Visible = true;

Comment: textBox1.Visible = !checkBox3.Checked

Comment: Other than make it disappeared, I know there's a way to somehow deactivate the textbox right? Like make the textbox become light color. How do we do this?

Comment: @maniac84 These are very simple questions that are freely answered in any tutorial. I would suggest referencing MSDN for these types of questions, or Googling first. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxxy49h(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Could you guys lift the ban on me... Give me another chance.